# Jquery doesn't see tag

Tags: jquery

So i have a html file and i tried to do some stuff in it with jquery, this is what i wrote in html file in the head tag

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/style.css" type="text/css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src=" js/script.js"></script>
</head>
```

and this  is the content of the script file

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $("div").hide();
 });
```

this was written just to test it out but for some reason it doesn't work

ok i have deleted the second script tag still nothing changed

```
<body>    
  <div class="lng">
    <ul>
       <li><a href="#">E</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">R</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">L</a></li>           
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
```

this is my code in html file

Comment: You don't include 2 jquery's in the same page.

Comment: wheres the rest of the code

Comment: Remove this line, you only need one version of jquery: `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>`

Comment: Include only one version of jQuery (full or min), can you post your simple full html?

Comment: The `div` that you're trying to hide doesn't look like it exists! Add a `<body><div>This is hidden</div></body>` to the bottom of your HTML file - if you don't see anything then your jQuery script has worked :)

Comment: Check your console, is your script.js file loaded?

Comment: Try adding alert in ready() method. If alert is displayed probably you jQuery is registered and working

Comment: Works fine on jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/debUn/

Answer (score -2):

Ok so i found that there was no problem in the tags or code, the problem was that, i was trying out one cloud IDE and when you press to run for some reason it doesn't run the scripts. I have found it out because i have downloaded the project and open the html file just with the browser and it works just fine.